# Static attributes in Cheetah

Tags: python, python-3.x, cheetah

I'm working on a project using Cheetah. I'd like to create a class like the following one:

```
from Cheetah.Template import Template
class TemplateObject(Template):
    className = "Default ClassName"
    def header(self):
        return "My Class name is {}".format(type(self).className)
```

and then i'd like to be able in one of my template to do something like:

```
#extends TemplateObject
#staticarg className = "CustomClassName" ## Something to declare a static member ?
$self.header()
```

is it possible to do this ?

Thank you

Comment: Sorry for late answer, I was in a hospital.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [#attr](http://cheetahtemplate.org/users_guide/inheritanceEtc.html#attr).

Example:

```
#attr className = "CustomClassName"
```